# Transform a string to an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a string like this:

```
(A,X(B,C,D),X(E,F),G,H)
```

and i want to transform it to to an array like this :

```
[{A}, {X(B,C,D)}, {X(E,F)}, {G}, {H}]
```

The input String can have nested elements like this

```
(A,X(B,X(A,B),D))
```

I thought to do it with tree structure.
What is the best way to do it in java ?

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: yes, then do it?

Comment: Use String.split(",")

Comment: @Sascha the String.split() does not work in this case

Comment: @Youssef Then you have to do it like a parser. Iterate over the chars and decide, if it is a comma you separate on or not. Have a flag for the info if its after an opening or closing bracket should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String text="(A,X(B,C(G,H),D),X(E,F),G,H)";

    int brackets=0;
    int lastComma=0;
    List<String> parts=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<text.length()-1;i++)
    {
        char c=text.charAt(i);
        if(c=='(')
            brackets++;
        else if(c==')')
            brackets--;
        else if(c==',' && brackets==0)
        {
            parts.add("{"+text.substring(lastComma+1,i)+"}");
            lastComma=i;
        }
    }
    parts.add("{"+text.substring(lastComma+1,text.length()-1)+"}");

    System.out.println(parts); //[{A}, {X(B,C(G,H),D)}, {X(E,F)}, {G}, {H}]
```

Comment: that's it thank you sir, one thing the last element disappeared but i will try to figure it out why

Comment: I edited my code to correct that oversight of me. Check the line after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your string doesn't have inner nested parenthesis like your above example you could use split:

```
String str = "(A,X(B,C,D),X(E,F),G,H)";

String[] splited = str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(",(?![^()]*\\))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));

//output: [A, X(B,C,D), X(E,F), G, H]
```

Comment: unfortunately it can have nested arguments like this "(A,X(B,X(A,B),D),X(E,F),G,H)"

Comment: And what would the desired output look like for such an input?

Comment: [{A}, {X(B,X(A,B),D)}, {X(E,F)}, {G}, {H}]